# datatables using codeigniter does not add result to table

Tags: php, datatables, codeigniter-3

I am trying to display search results into a table using DataTables. I am getting search results into JSON and validated also against valid JSON, but I get this DataTables warning:

> table id=volunteer_result - Invalid JSON response.

For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1.

I have used below codes :

views: searchdemo.php

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button id="search_demo" class="btn btn-form">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="demo_result_div" class="table-responsive" style="background-color:#fff;">
    <table  id="demo_result" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

js: searchdemo.js

```
var table;
$('#search_demo').click(function () {
    //datatables
    table = $('#demo_result').DataTable({ 

        "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
        "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' servermside processing mode.
        //"order": [], //Initial no order.
        "iDisplayLength" : 10,

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo site_url('/demo/searchdemo')?>",
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "dataSrc": function (jsonData) {
                return jsonData.data;
            }
        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],
    });
});
```

controller:Demo.php

```
class Demo extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('demo/Demo_model');
    }

    public function index() {
    }
    public function searchdemo() {
        $data['branch_list'] = $this->Demo_model->get_company_branches();

        // set form validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'trim|required');

        // submit
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            // validation failed, send validation errors to the view
            $data['branch_list'] = $this->Demo_model->get_company_branches();
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('demo/searchdemo',$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {                
            // set variables from the form              
            $formdata = array(
                'branch_id' => $this->input->post('branch'),
                'length' => intval($this->input->post('length')),
                'start' => intval($this->input->post('start')),
                'order' => $this->input->post('order')
            );
            $users_list = $this->Demo_model->get_user_details($formdata); 
            if(!empty($users_list )){
                $data = array();
                foreach ($users_list as $user) {
                    $row = array();
                    $row['name'] = $user->name;
                    $row['role'] = $user->role;
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
            }
        }

        $output = array(
            "draw" => intval($this->input->post('draw')),
            "recordsTotal" => $this->Demo_model->count_all_active($formdata),
            "recordsFiltered" => $this->Demo_model->count_filtered($formdata),
            "data" => $data
        );

        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
}
```

model:Demo_model.php

```
class Demo_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = "users u";  
    var $select_column = array("u.id", "u.name", "ur.role");  
    var $column_order = array(null, "u.name","ur.role");
    var $order = array('u.name' => 'asc'); // default order

    function make_query($formdata) {  
        if($formdata['branch_id']) {
            $this->db->select($this->select_column);  
            $this->db->from($this->table);      
            $this->db->where('u.active','yes');
            $this->db->where('u.branch_id',$formdata['branch_id']);
            $this->db->join('user_role ur','u.role_id=ur.id');
        }
        if(isset($_POST['order'])) { // here order processing
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$formdata['order']['0']['column']], $formdata['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order)) {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_user_details($formdata){   
        $this->make_query($formdata); 

        if(isset($formdata['length']) && $formdata['length'] < 1) {
            $formdata['length']= '10';
        } else {
            $formdata['length']= $formdata['length'];
        }
        if(isset($formdata['start']) && $formdata['start'] > 1) {
            $formdata['start']= $formdata['start'];
        }
        $this->db->limit($formdata['length'], $formdata['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

When I select a branch from the dropdown and click on Search button, it just returns the below JSON into the web browser instead of displaying results into search page table.

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 2000,
    "recordsFiltered": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Raman",
            "role": "manager"
        },
        {
            "name": "Maharaja",
            "role": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I referred this link https://www.phpflow.com/php/server-side-datatable-sorting-searching-pagination-using-codeigniter-ii/

I have tried the many help URL for data table invalid JSON response but didn't get any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define data source for each column using [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) option.

Change your initialization code as shown below:

```
var table = $('#demo_result').DataTable({ 
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('/demo/searchdemo')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name", "orderable": false },
        { "data": "role" }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I tried this but i got the same warning "invalid JSON response"

Comment: @Shan, also `draw` would never be `0` in the request, it usually starts at `1`, there must be something else wrong. Are you sure that `$this->input->post('draw')` gets request parameter `draw`?